# excel multiple before double click actions

Tags: vba, excel

**What I Have:**

`BeforeDoubleClick` event to change an `entirerow.font.color` from black to red if a cell from `column A` is double clicked. *This shows that I added a new item.*

`-`

**What I am trying to do:**

How can I also have a double click event on only single cells between `columns E:X`? *This would show if we changed quantity on an existing item.*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Excel.Range, Cancel As Boolean)
finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

If Not Application.Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("A9:A" & finalrow)) Is Nothing Then
 If Target.Font.Color = vbRed Then
     Target.EntireRow.Font.Color = vbBlack
 Else
     Target.EntireRow.Font.Color = vbRed
 End If
End If
Cancel = True
End Sub
```

> Edit: Got it to work with the following...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Excel.Range, Cancel As Boolean)
finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

If Not Application.Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("A9:A" & finalrow)) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Font.Color = vbRed Then
        Target.EntireRow.Font.Color = vbBlack
        Else
        Target.EntireRow.Font.Color = vbRed
    End If
End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E9:X500")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Font.Color = vbRed Then
        Target.Font.Color = vbBlack
        Else
        Target.Font.Color = vbRed
    End If
End If

Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to conditionally color cells in E:X and NOT ever change them again by your EntireRow double-click event after a cell in E:X has changed?

Comment: Add another `If...Then` block to check for intersect with Cols E:X and then take the appropriate action